# Where is request.param(...) in Go

Tags: http, go

Here is my console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/photos.json?token=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

200 OK
    0   
jquery.js (line 8526)
|Params|    Headers    Response    JSON
token   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

I am in the params tab. How do I access this and, for example log token to my terminal window.

In node: request.param('token')

Comment: Why jquery and node here ? Is that a Go question or not ?

Comment: OP, you should probably accept an answer (Baba's one, it's better than mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [func (*Request) FormValue](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue)

> [FormValue](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) returns the first value for the named component of the query. POST and PUT body parameters take precedence over URL query string values. FormValue calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary. To access multiple values of the same key use ParseForm.

Simple Server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)

}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter , r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<html><body><h1>Hello ", r.FormValue("token") , "</h1></body></html>")
}
```

Visit `localhost:4000/photos.json?token=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` you would get

```
Hello ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't knew this function and always called `hr.Form`. Is that a new function ?

Comment: It's `request.Form`, and many people alias request as `r` as in `r *http.Request`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a `http.Request`. Let's suppose it's called `hr`.

Then you can do

```
hr.ParseForm()
```

and after that you may use `hr.Form` which is defined like this :

```
// Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL
// field's query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.
// This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
// The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.
Form url.Values
```

where `url.Values` is a map :

```
type Values map[string][]string
```

Here's an example of use of a parsed form where I'm only interested in the first value for a given name :

```
func getFormValue(hr *http.Request, name string) string {
    if values := hr.Form[name]; len(values) > 0 {
        return values[0]
    }
    return ""
}
```